# Multiple parameters in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

I know this question is asked many times and I still get problems when I follow the [guide](http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html) when including multiple parameters in my select query. Here is my configuration file:

```
<select id="selectByDate" parameterType="map" resultMap="campaignStats">
    SELECT * FROM CampaignStats WHERE statsDate >= #{start} AND statsDate <= #{end}
</select>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public List<DpCampaignStats> selectByDate(Date start, Date end){
    SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        Map<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
        map.put("start", start);
        map.put("end", end);
        List<DpCampaignStats> list = session.selectList("DpCampaignStats.selectByDate", map);
        return list;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

But I get the error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError which means that I have some errors in my configuration file and I cannot find the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself: '<' and '>' have certain meanings in xml files, so the '>=' should be '*&gt;*=' while the '<=' should be '*&lt;*='.

Comment: escaping of '>' to &gt; is not necessary

Answer (score 11):

Just wrap you SQL statement in CDATA:

```
<![CDATA[
   SELECT * FROM CampaignStats WHERE statsDate >= #{start} AND statsDate <= #{end}
]]>
```